# Two identities involving binomial coefficients and double factorials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, alternating-expression

I'm trying to prove the following identities:
$$\forall t\geqslant2,\forall 0\leqslant i\leqslant\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2}\right\rfloor,S_{\text{even}}(i, t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{t}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{t}{2k}(2i+2k-1)!!(2t-2i-2k-1)!!=(-1)^it!$$
$$\forall t\geqslant2,\forall 0\leqslant i\leqslant\left\lfloor\frac{t-1}{2}\right\rfloor,S_{\text{odd}}(i, t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{t-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{t}{2k+1}(2i+2k+1)!!(2t-2i-2k-3)!!=(-1)^it!$$
Numerically, this holds for the first values of $i$ and $t$. What I've tried so far:

- Induction on $t$: it changes the summand too much for it to work in the general case. We do have $S_{\text{odd}}(0,t+1)=(t+1)S_{\text{even}}(0, t)$ though, so if we manage to show that increasing $i$ flips the sign, we could consider only the case $i=0$ and that would be great.
- "Induction" on $i$, or more exactly trying to prove that increasing or decreasing $i$ leads to flipping the sign of the result. Clearly, the summand of $S_{\text{even}}(i+1, t)$ and $S_{\text{odd}}(i, t)$ are very similar, but the binomial coefficient prevents us from getting an immediate relation. We can sum them using the summation formula for binomial coefficient, but I don't see an immediate way to justify that this sum is nil.
- Find an existing formula. I found two potentially relevant paper concerning this point, namely [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.1317.pdf) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10196.pdf). The first one contain sums that are kind of similar but that are not alternates, the second one contains alternate sums but with stirling numbers.
- Use combinatorics. Notably, the fact that this is an alternate sum makes me think of the onclusion-exclusion principle, but I didn't find a clever way to map this quantity to something that can be counted.

Is there a simple way to prove these identities? Or even better, are they already proven or are they a direct application of some more general identity that I've missed?